# Javascript Arrays created with Object.create - not real Arrays?

Tags: javascript, v8, object-create

It looks like Arrays created with Object.create walk like Arrays and quack like Arrays, but are still not real arrays. At least with v8 / node.js.

```
> a = []
[]
> b = Object.create(Array.prototype)
{}
> a.constructor
[Function: Array]
> b.constructor
[Function: Array]
> a.__proto__
[]
> b.__proto__
[]
> a instanceof Array
true
> b instanceof Array
true
> Object.prototype.toString.call(a)
'[object Array]'
> Object.prototype.toString.call(b)
'[object Object]'
```

Can some Javascript guru explain why it is so, and how to make it so that my newly created array is indistinguishable from a real array?

My goal here is to clone data structures, including Arrays which may have custom properties attached. I could, of course, manually attach properties to a newly-created Array using `Object.defineProperty`, but is there a way to do so using `Object.create`?

Comment: They're rather indistinguishable for your goal.
How to make fully indistingushable -- use `b = []`;

Comment: @kirilloid - that might be a valid approach for some situations but in situations where say a factory function internally does the plumbing based on a prototypeParam, your suggestion is not an option. eg. in the creation of a monoid, start with: var monad = Object.create(prototypeParam);  Here, it would be convenient if prototypeParam could be Array.prototype

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is no. [This article](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/) explains it all in some detail.

Comment: See http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2292-Extending-JavaScript-Arrays-While-Keeping-Native-Bracket-Notation-Functionality.htm for a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot. `Object.create` is all about prototypes, but both `[]` and `Object.create(Array.prototype)` inherit from the same prototype object.

What you call "*desired Object.prototype.toString behaviour*" is the internal `[[Class]]` of the object, which is impossible to set up with `Object.create`. Creating "true arrays" (with an `Array` class and [special array behaviour](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.5) - indexed properties, `.length`) is only possible by using [array literals](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.4) or [calling the `Array` constructor](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.1).