# Why is Object.prototype.toString.call(arr) returning [object Object] instead of [object Array]?

Tags: javascript

Please have a look at the below code

```
function Abc(){}

Abc.prototype=new Array();

var arr= new Abc();
```

The following conditions returns true..

1) `Array.prototype.isPrototypeOf(arr);//true`

2) `arr instanceof Array //true`

But `Object.prototype.toString.call(arr);` is returning `[object Object]`

why is it returning `[object Object]` instead of `[object Array]`?

Thanks!

Comment: or maybe better duplicates would have been [Array.isArray() returns false for array created with Object.create()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34178006/1048572), [Javascript Arrays created with Object.create - not real Arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9016051/1048572) and [new Array() vs Object.create(Array.prototype)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22022058/1048572)

Answer (score 2):

[`toString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2) gets the "value of the [[Class]] internal property of O". It doesn't look up the prototype chain.

Comment: so, no way to output _[object Array]_ in this case?

Comment: You could override `Abc.prototype.toString()` with your own function.

Comment: but `Object.prototype.toString.call(arr)` still return _[object Object]_

Comment: @Grundy: Of course it is, when you call it onto an object.

Comment: @Grundy: In ES6 you could overwrite `Abc.prototype[Symbol.toStringTag]` but I'd rather avoid that. And of course you wouldn't need it at all if you'd properly do `class Abc extends Array …` :-)

Comment: You could override Abc.prototype.toString() with your own function … and call it instead of grabbing Object's toString.

Comment: @Bergi, OMG! don't know about this

Comment: But Object.prototype.toString.call(arr) the recommended way for checking for Array-ness [stoyan stefanov's javascript patterns]. Does it mean that Abc is not an Array even though we are doing Abc.prototype=new Array()?